# Is it possible to fetch data from multiple Google Analytics tables in one request?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Looking at the API documentation linked below makes me confused. The parameter name "ids" suggest due to its plural form of "id" that I should be able to fetch data from multiple tables in one request, right?

However, this (vaguely) suggest the opposite:

> The unique table ID used to retrieve the Analytics Report data. This ID is provided by the  element for each entry in the account feed. This value is composed of the ga: namespace and the view (profile) ID of the web property. 
>   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataReferenceDataFeed#ids

What I want to do is fetch visitor data from more than one table in one request and get them summed up and ready to use.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You will need to make 2 separate requests for each table ID.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why it's called "ids" and not "id"? It's very confusing.